# Strange question when assign multiple values in Python

Tags: python

Given an array
`nums=[3,2,1,0]`

when I run this code:

```
i=0
nums[i],i=None,nums[i]
print(i,nums)
>>>3 [None, 2, 1, 0]
```

But when I change the order of value assignment

```
i=0
i,nums[i]=nums[i],None
print(i,nums)
>>>3 [3, 2, 1, None]
```

This makes me feel confused because I think the assignment happens simultaneously

Here, in my first code snippet, it runs as expected, nums[i] is set to None and i is set to old nums[i]at the same time

But in the second code snippet, it seems that i is set to 3 first, and then nums[3] is set to None.

Comment: No, that linked question does not address this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation order can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). The relevant section would be:

```
expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
```

Where we have, in order:

- expr1: `nums[i]` evaluated to 3
- expr2: `None`
- expr3: `i` set to the result of expr1
- expr4: `nums[i]` where the `i` used is set in expr3.

That order of operations, specifically in this case where our fourth expression is based on our third, is what is messing it up.

Comment: Neat, I would've picked that as implementation detail rather than canonically documented! TIL!

Comment: BTW, for further experimentation, we could define an object with properties (or overriding `[]`) then `print` when each of the getters and setters is called; however, the documentation is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned that the assignments work left to right.

Although, first, the expression on the right hand side of the `=` is evaluated, then the items on the left hand side are assigned, one-at-a-time.

This mean that in the second snippet you will have:

```py
i = nums[i]     #  first
nums[i] = None  # second
```

It looks like, here, that `i` is modified before the second assignment takes place.